# NestedScrollView size is not fit to CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am tring to apply CollapsingToolbarLayout in my app.

Below XML works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <ViewSwitcher
                    android:id="@+id/switcherTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/title"
                        android:textSize="36sp"/>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="@string/title"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:textSize="36sp"/>
                </ViewSwitcher>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_save_confirm_action_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_36dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/collapsingToolbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adBannerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5185146194441120/1301019297"/>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But there is one issue.

NestedScrollView over the screen.

It is not fit in its parent height.

[image]

When I apply below code, it is helpful.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

This mean that should I control using "actionBarHeight"?

Is there any other smart way?

Comment: you were able to fix it? If yes please help by posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call setSupportActionBar with your toolbar in the Activity onCreate method.

i.e.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `minHeight` attribute in your CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Similar issue and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654007/4656400)