# CollapsingToolbarLayout pushes NestedScrollView down in android

Tags: android

I encountered a problem on first launch of a fragment. It seems like CoordinatorLayout adds a negative margin to NestedScrollView which is equal to CollapsingToolbarLayout's height in collapsed state (I tested it by changing the height's value). As a result RecyclerView which lives in the NestedScrollView cannot scroll up to show few of its bottom items.

There are some similar questions on SO (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306559/nestedscrollview-wontt-scroll-to-the-end-when-used-with-collapsingtoolbarlayout), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42934442/nestedscrollview-size-is-not-fit-to-collapsingtoolbarlayout) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33712401/why-nestedscrollview-stop-scrolling-when-collapsingtoolbarlayout-is-completely-c/33777902#33777902)), but they don't provide a solution that worked for me, and moreover, they don't give any explanations of what can cause the issue.

One interesting note is that if I rotate, or turn the screen off and on it would rebuild the layout and afterwords it will show up correctly. Also, if I click on an item it will trigger something so then I would be able to scroll those hidden items. As a workaround it would be nice to call a function that rebuilds the layout correctly manually but I failed to figure out what it was (see what I tried to do below)

What I tried to do:

- adding bottom margin equal to toolbar's height to NestedScrollView. Although it helped on first launch but after I clicked on an item or rotate the screen the extra margin would push the view up from the bottom of the screen.
- I couldn't find any problem in my code while debugging.
- calling getView.invalidate() didn't help as well.

Can somebody help me to figure out what can cause the issue, please?

fragment_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.orgin.glagol.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <include layout="@layout/player_view"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/player_toolbar_height"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

        <ViewAnimator
            android:id="@+id/viewAnimator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"
            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/empty_history_books" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/error_loading_data" />

        </ViewAnimator>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Update:**
Still don't know the reason but it seems like adding `minHeight` attribute to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `minHeight` attribute prevents CollapsingToolbarLayout from unexpected behavior:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_always_elevated">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/player_toolbar_height"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <include layout="@layout/player_view"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/player_toolbar_height"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```